# Windows 7 Embedded VM in Azure

Tags: azure, windows-7, embedded

I have a really weird request.

My employer has a product that only runs on Windows 7 embedded machines and now they want to have some test VMs in Azure.

Now when I try to RDP into the machine it doesn't connect (locally I can RDP to the machine so RDP settings are correct).

What I did:

1. Set up a Local Windows Server 2019 machine that runs Hyper-V.
2. The Windows 7 Embedded machine has been captured with Macrium Reflect and runs in VIBoot/Hyper-V
3. The machine will only work when I use the "Legacy Network Adapter" function in Hyper-V
4. I have set-up failover from this machine into Azure
5. The machine fails over in Azure and I can see the VM and see that it boots correctly in the "Boot Diagnostics" tab
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVIYw.png

(Machine boots, does an autologon and this error was expected so everything went as expected).

6. Added a public IP address/network adapter.
7. Now while it is starting I saw it gave me a "network adapter unplugged" notification in the bottom right.
8. Manually installed the Azure agent as per [instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows) and tried failover again.

Does anyone have an idea that can help me further along?

I'm not looking for all the many many many ways this is bad practice as I am already aware and have already communicated that.

The alternative would be to have a Server2019 HV host in Azure and have this Windows 7 Embedded run Nested as a VM on that VM but that is wasting quite some resources and would prefer to do it without the intermediate Server.

Comment: What series VM are you running in Azure?

Comment: B series, should be sufficient for a test setup or is there something I missed that is available in another series?

Comment: I would consider a Dv3 or Dsv3-series.  These series are designed to run HyperV and while I know that is not your first choice they may have the networking hardware you need for this application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [Hyper-V Integration Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/Manage-Hyper-V-integration-services) in your VM before migrating it to Azure, otherwise it will not have the appropriate drivers to run in Hyper-V (and thus in Azure); specifically, it will be lacking the NIC drivers and thus will have no networking.

However, the HVIS ISO image is not available anymore on Windows Server 2016 and 2019, because Hyper-V drivers have been integrated into Windows for a while; the only way to get a copy of it is to retrieve it from the Windows Server 2012 R2 install media or from a Windows Server 2012 R2 server with the Hyper-V role installed, as documented [here](https://smudj.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/vmguest-iso-for-older-windows-oses-in-win102016/). There are also various copies of it floating around the Internet, such as described [here](https://www.deltik.org/news/view/45/download-hyper-v-integration-services-for-legacy-operating-systems).

Comment: Ah forgot to mention that, I have tried that but to no avail, the Server2008R2 drivers do not work for Windows 7 embedded it seems.
I tried manually installing it with DISM/PKGMGR but that errored out (I'll see if I can reproduce the error and post it in the question.

This was actually part of another issue I tried to resolve which was that the VM would only have mouse support if I used Windows 10 as a Host OS but the mouse would not work on a Server2019 Host.
I ended up figuring out that the mouse worked fine in RDP so I start the VM and just RDP to it instead of using Hyper-V's Monitor

Comment: If you can't get the Hyper-V network drivers to work (which seems to be the case, as you said the VM only works if using a legacy network adapter), then that VM will never be able to run in Azure.

Comment: Also, you need to install the version of HVIS bundled with Windows Server 2012 R2, not the one from Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Have you tried downloading `vmguest.iso` from the last page I linked and running the installer inside the VM?

Comment: Hmmm I thought since 2008R2 is the Server equivalent of Windows 7 that would be the one that had the correct version of the vmguest.iso.
I will try the 2012R2 version of that ISO.

Comment: WS2008R2 has an older version of the HVIS, which needs to be updated to WS2012R2 level in order to run on more recent Hyper-V systems; the same goes for Windows 7.